# Passing function to child component from react showing it as undefined

Tags: reactjs, callback

In my code i have

```
....
setPin = (pin) => {
    console.log(this.state)
    this.setState({pin})
}
return (
  <div>
   {console.log("this.props --",this.setPin)}
   <ReactKeyboard isNumberOnly onChange={this.setpin} />
  </div>    
)
```

ReactKeyboard is child component and it have button so on click i callback onChange function.

But

In console i can see output of `{console.log("this.props --",this.setPin)}` which is function and in child component I have

```
keyPress(key){
      const { onChange } = {...this.props};
      console.log("onChange",onChange)
      console.log("props",this.props)
      onChange(key);
    };
```

In here it is throwing error that **onChange is not function** and if i check in console onChange is undefined.

Why so ? Parent is showing function value correct but in child it is showing undefined ?

Console output is
[image]

We can check that props in child have function as undefined

---

I am now getting
[image]

`Uncaught TypeError: this.setpin is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

make `keyPress` as arrow function.

```
keyPress = key => {
    const { onChange } = this.props;
    console.log("onChange",onChange);
    console.log("props",this.props);
    onChange(key);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This was because i was using `.bind` and fat arrow to bind function at same time. My bad.